# How to get specific information from API data from Greenbits using Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Been working on a project and finally got it to connect to the API and pull the data, now just just need certain information from the information pulled.

Looking at trying to get just the Quantity total for the item so I place it into a variable and then utilize the information within the script.
This is how the information looks when its pull from the API.

```
{
  "inventory_items": [
    {
      "id": "dc558fe9-7c1f-41c3-ba90-fe4d602e57ca",
      "sku": "1234567890123459",
      "quantity": 5,
      "weight": null,
      "purchase_price": 666,
      "lot_number": "1234567890123459",
      "sell_type": 3,
      "sample": false,
      "transferred_out": false,
      "received_at": "2020-09-07T09:40:59.000Z",
      "metadata": null,
      "test_results_thc": "0.13",
      "test_results_cbd": "0.04",
      "sellable_quantity": 0,
      "product": {
        "id": "1ee050d1-d08f-4bea-840e-f3a3a01d994a",
        "sku": null,
        "name": "AK-47",
        "sell_price": 1400,
        "collect_excise_tax": true,
        "quantity": 107,
        "pricing_type": 0,
        "vendor": "Katz Kush Farms",
        "active": true,
        "latest_sku": "1234567890123455",
        "weight": null,
        "tags": [],
        "description": null,
        "internal_notes": null,
        "metadata": null,
        "test_results_thc": "0.35",
        "test_results_cbd": "0.005",
        "flower_type": 1,
        "concentrate_type": null,
        "category_id": "76f4b09d-a49a-4e83-bdc7-7424ffe6ee4f",
        "brand_id": "774ef7ee-38ab-469a-9789-9b53aaeab229",
        "strain_id": "abcdec1a-2020-42e8-adbe-621efb760000",
        "product_type_id": "882d74f6-d0fa-4abb-a962-02c32f229fb0"
      },
      "inventory_item_places": [
        {
          "id": "d6eb5219-eac3-4e58-9dd7-0f2e5d070daf",
          "quantity": {
            "value": "0.0",
            "unit": 0
          },
          "sellable_quantity": {
            "value": "0.0",
            "unit": 0
          },
          "inventory_status": 0,
          "place_id": "d4668dd4-ea5f-49b2-8acf-6b1defc4db6e",
          "inventory_item_id": "dc558fe9-7c1f-41c3-ba90-fe4d602e57ca"
        },
        {
          "id": "1d965dcf-f72c-4b4f-abfc-99551934c3f5",
          "quantity": {
            "value": "0.0",
            "unit": 0
          },
          "sellable_quantity": {
            "value": "0.0",
            "unit": 0
          },
          "inventory_status": 1,
          "place_id": "26f3b975-ac94-4810-9ad8-643a2b3aeb79",
          "inventory_item_id": "dc558fe9-7c1f-41c3-ba90-fe4d602e57ca"
        },
        {
          "id": "45b10003-6137-4e6a-add5-9e5bc2e783a0",
          "quantity": {
            "value": "5.0",
            "unit": 0
          },
          "sellable_quantity": {
            "value": "0.0",
            "unit": 0
          },
          "inventory_status": 3,
          "place_id": "77755ba4-6437-4f75-a482-cbf7ee69b70a",
          "inventory_item_id": "dc558fe9-7c1f-41c3-ba90-fe4d602e57ca"
        },
        {
          "id": "83f42262-63af-4fba-9d25-4babff6a157e",
          "quantity": {
            "value": "0.0",
            "unit": 0
          },
          "sellable_quantity": {
            "value": "0.0",
            "unit": 0
          },
          "inventory_status": 2,
          "place_id": "59cf8b9c-78c2-499d-aff1-8d21c022d3e4",
          "inventory_item_id": "dc558fe9-7c1f-41c3-ba90-fe4d602e57ca"
        },
        {
          "id": "9010f610-8567-4f27-aace-bae582952aad",
          "quantity": {
            "value": "0.0",
            "unit": 0
          },
          "sellable_quantity": {
            "value": "0.0",
            "unit": 0
          },
          "inventory_status": 4,
          "place_id": "5327118e-4f44-4a62-9417-c9306159f5d6",
          "inventory_item_id": "dc558fe9-7c1f-41c3-ba90-fe4d602e57ca"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "total": 1
  }
}
```

Not sure if its an array of sorts, I believe it to be a JSON file of types.
Im fairly new to scripting in general but I have a decent idea of logic and structure.

If someone would be able to help direct me towards the right function/process to use towards this it would be great.  I feel like I am flopping like a fish without an idea of where to jump towards.

Here is the script i have for it.

```
    function getGreenbitsProduct()
{

  var options = {};
  options.headers = {"Authorization": "Token token=" + greenbitsToken};
  response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.greenbits.com/api/v1/inventory_items?by_product_name=Jack Herer - (3.5g) - Artizen", options);
  Logger.log(response);
  var object = JSON.parse("quantity");
  Logger.log(object);
```

This is the information that is being pulled and the 19 and 45 are in there, but there is 68 between them but i cant seem to access this needed information

```
{inventory_items=[{weight=3.5, id=d45a1231-dc99-4c5c-adee-c5b6251f319d, quantity=19.0, transferred_out=false, test_results_thc=null, sellable_quantity=0.0, purchase_price=1600.0, sell_type=0.0, sku=GF41228800001740, inventory_item_places=[], metadata=null, product={brand_id=63ac989e-bbda-4d96-8f9e-9503c5d83fa3, pricing_type=null, concentrate_type=null, tags=[], weight={value=3.5, unit=0.0}, active=true, internal_notes=null, collect_excise_tax=true, sell_price=4500.0, sku=null, id=35b3a059-1bdf-4ea0-a404-63818a311cbf, vendor=BACON'S BUDS, latest_sku=GF41228800003709, strain_id=4121ae5b-a148-49ad-a535-ef30d3c3eb91, category_id=1f216f97-4505-4714-9853-07c2f7a9e0da, test_results_cbd=null, metadata=null, product_type_id=94de8728-506e-4b83-8688-56d63ff723ce, name=Falcon 9 - (3.5g) - Bacon's Buds, flower_type=3.0, test_results_thc=0.221, description=That indica-dominant strain from Exotic Genetix crosses Sunset Sherbert with Tina. Falcon 9 is noted for a smooth, gassy ice cream flavor profile that comes from dark purple buds accented by vibrant orange pistils. Meant for indica lovers, Falcon 9 is known to start as a strong head high before settling into the body., quantity=67.0}, sample=false, test_results_cbd=null, received_at=2022-01-29T18:52:57.000Z, lot_number=GF41228800001740}, {id=c18001c1-cd05-4595-a5cb-1624b6bdcfea, transferred_out=false, sample=false, weight=3.5, received_at=2022-03-01T17:31:12.000Z, product={vendor=BACON'S BUDS, product_type_id=94de8728-506e-4b83-8688-56d63ff723ce, latest_sku=GF41228800003709, category_id=1f216f97-4505-4714-9853-07c2f7a9e0da, pricing_type=null, strain_id=4121ae5b-a148-49ad-a535-ef30d3c3eb91, sku=null, quantity=67.0, brand_id=63ac989e-bbda-4d96-8f9e-9503c5d83fa3, description=That indica-dominant strain from Exotic Genetix crosses Sunset Sherbert with Tina. Falcon 9 is noted for a smooth, gassy ice cream flavor profile that comes from dark purple buds accented by vibrant orange pistils. Meant for indica lovers, Falcon 9 is known to start as a strong head high before settling into the body., weight={unit=0.0, value=3.5}, active=true, sell_price=4500.0, test_results_cbd=null, collect_excise_tax=true, internal_notes=null, test_results_thc=0.221, name=Falcon 9 - (3.5g) - Bacon's Buds, id=35b3a059-1bdf-4ea0-a404-63818a311cbf, metadata=null, flower_type=3.0, concentrate_type=null, tags=[]}, test_results_cbd=0.0, test_results_thc=0.23, metadata=null, sku=GF41228800003709, sellable_quantity=0.0, lot_number=null, sell_type=0.0, purchase_price=1600.0, inventory_item_places=[], quantity=45.0}, {lot_number=WAR422194.IN12UC4J, purchase_price=1600.0, inventory_item_places=[], id=7295553c-b7f7-4c76-8be2-c207a4e30d75, test_results_cbd=null, received_at=2021-11-17T17:12:06.000Z, sku=WAJ412288.IN12F8WB, quantity=3.0, sample=false, weight=null, test_results_thc=null, sell_type=0.0, sellable_quantity=0.0, metadata=null, transferred_out=false, product={strain_id=4121ae5b-a148-49ad-a535-ef30d3c3eb91, quantity=67.0, test_results_cbd=null, category_id=1f216f97-4505-4714-9853-07c2f7a9e0da, weight={unit=0.0, value=3.5}, product_type_id=94de8728-506e-4b83-8688-56d63ff723ce, description=That indica-dominant strain from Exotic Genetix crosses Sunset Sherbert with Tina. Falcon 9 is noted for a smooth, gassy ice cream flavor profile that comes from dark purple buds accented by vibrant orange pistils. Meant for indica lovers, Falcon 9 is known to start as a strong head high before settling into the body., vendor=BACON'S BUDS, internal_notes=null, tags=[], id=35b3a059-1bdf-4ea0-a404-63818a311cbf, collect_excise_tax=true, sell_price=4500.0, name=Falcon 9 - (3.5g) - Bacon's Buds, concentrate_type=null, sku=null, brand_id=63ac989e-bbda-4d96-8f9e-9503c5d83fa3, flower_type=3.0, active=true, metadata=null, latest_sku=GF41228800003709, test_results_thc=0.221, pricing_type=null}}]}
```

Comment: If your data is put in `object`, the value of `object.inventory_items[0].quantity` is the result you expect? In this case, when your data is used, `5` is retrieved. For example, in your actual data, the array of `inventory_items` has multiple elements?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
Is the error it gives me when i used that to try and get the information.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`, in this case, your showing data is the JSON object or the string data? I cannot see your script. So I commented it using your provided information. I deeply apologize for this. If your showing data is the string value, please use `var object = JSON.parse("your string value")` and test it again.

Comment: When the script is put in the comment, I think that the readability becomes low. So can you post it to your question?

Comment: Yeah updated it via that.
It just seems like a big mess that gets pulled.
Appears to be pulling multiple of the same named products from the API im requesting, but its all the same, and the first quantity shows the total quantity for the product anyway.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Where can I see your current script? And, when you tested my proposed method `var object = JSON.parse("your string value")`, what result did you obtain?

Comment: var object = JSON.parse("quantity");
SyntaxError: Unexpected token q in JSON at position 0

Comment: Thank you for replying. If `Logger.log(response);` of your provided script is the showing script, please modify `var object = JSON.parse("quantity");` to `var object = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());`. And please check `console.log(object.inventory_items[0].quantity)`.

Comment: So yes that object.inventory_items[0].quantity got the 16 i was looking for in the section.  Would you be able to explain to me why that all worked and how it worked?
I just like a better understand as to why and how it worked so i know how to utilize it later for other things such as this.  As i may need to get other information out of the list.  if i changed that quantity to quantity[1] would it pull the 2nd quantity in this list? or if i changed it to a different information like sale_price etc. would this also function?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About the JSON data, for example, you can see the document at [https://www.json.org/json-en.html](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). And also, from your script, I thought that [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) will be useful. About your new question, I cannot understand what you want to do. Can I ask you about the detail of your new question? By the way, the property of `sale_price` is not included in your showing data. What is it?

Comment: So after messing with it, i assume if i wanted the 2nd entry of quantity i would set inventory_items[1] to find the 2nd one and so forth, and since the json.parse split everything up within the json, then if i wanted a different bit of data from it i would just change object.inventory_items[0].NEWSEARCHEDITEM and it would give me the data from that?

Comment: About your new question of `So after messing with it, i assume if i wanted the 2nd entry of quantity i would set inventory_items[1] to find the 2nd one and so forth, and since the json.parse split everything up within the json, then if i wanted a different bit of data from it i would just change object.inventory_items[0].NEWSEARCHEDITEM and it would give me the data from that?`, I cannot understand your expected value from this. So I cannot clear answer it. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Can you provide the sample values you expect?

Comment: I was just confirming.
If i do object.inventory_items[1].quantity it would find the second listing of quantity.
as well if i do object.inventory_items[0].vendor it would find the vendor name as well.
More of a clarification on its abilities.

Comment: Hey Tanaike, so as i was moving forward for some reason some items i have are broke up into 2 different lots of products, but the total quantity is within the field so within each there are 2 quantity showing and the first is the single lot total and the 2nd is full product total.
I have tried object.inventory_items[0].quantity and object.inventory_items[1] and it provides me with the first lot number 19, or the 2nd lot number 45, not the total of 68.  Ill repost the information its pulling. i cant seem to get it on the other quantity...

Comment: actually it looks like "object.inventory_items[0].product.quantity" doing this fixed this issue... base on all your help i was able to break it apart and figure it out, THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved. Can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logger.log(response); of your provided script is the showing script, please modify var object = JSON.parse("quantity"); to var object = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());. And please check console.log(object.inventory_items[0].quantity)